# Multithreading and JSON/NSURLConnection on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, xcode, json

I am writing an app that uses multithreading and cache. Quite similar to Apple's [TopSongs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopSongs/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. Upon startup, I need to grab the value of an object in a JSON feed.

Now I am afraid doing so would ruin the workflow of the app, and block a thread or something if I use NSURLConnection. Can I just download that JSON feed (it only has one object) without using NSURLConnection's delegate methods? If I implement the delegate methods in my delegate file, then the app will finish up `applicationDidFinishLaunching:application` method and THEN go to

```
connection:didReceiveResponse:
connection:didReceiveData:
connection:didFailWithError:
connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

How can I avoid that? I need to get the timestamp (stored in that JSON file) right at the beginning of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:application` as the rest of that method depend on that timestamp.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

Use the **sendSynchronousRequest** of NSURLConnection, but this will block until a response is received

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

or (*the preferable option*)

Move the code which relies on the JSON to a seperate method. Use the asynchronous + delegate methods of NSURLConnection as normal, but in your **applicationDidFinishLaunching** method display [some sort of HUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to inform the user of what's happening and then in the **connection:didReceiveResponse** method or **connectionDidFinishLoading** method call your new method which relies on the JSON (*and will now have the JSON*) and dismiss the HUD.

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive reply. Just some clarifications before I mark this as the right answer: in the first solution, this will block all of the threads until the feed has been retrieved? Is this recommended/efficient or it depends on the situation?

Comment: @Nayefc This method is called on the main thread, so blocks that one and only that one. However, all the UI is drawn on the main thread so going down this route would make your app seem unresponsive on launch as all interaction would be blocked until the method returned a response. IMO the second option would be the preferred one and would provide a much better UX for the end user.

Comment: I am literally getting one string on a blank page from a website. Would a UI delay be noticed in this situation?

Comment: @Nayefc It doesn't specifically relate to the payload, more the entire requests round-trip (*for example the delay would be more significant if I were connected via Edge rather than 3G or WiFi*) but your best bet is to give it a try. On the flip side, if the request is *quick* then loading & displaying a HUD only to immediately dismiss it may also present a poor UX. I'm pretty sure that your *default.png* is displayed until **applicationDidFinishLaunching** returns, and if that's the case then this is trivial anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you said "the app will finish up applicationDidFinishLaunching and THEN go to

`connection:didReceiveResponse:
connection:didReceiveData:
connection:didFailWithError:
connectionDidFinishLoading:`"

Could you explain that a little more?

As for the point about the method depending on the timestamp that you need to get from the JSON file, I would suggest that you need to review your application design and what you are doing in your methods.

Comment: My app uses Core Data. Upon startup, it downloads data from the JSON feed and stores them using Core Data. The JSON feed does not get changed often so I have a JSON feed that stores the timestamp of the last update on the online database. It is also stored in NSUserDefaults. Now it checks if the last update timestamp in the feed is newer than the one stored in NSUserDefaults. If so, it re-downloads the data. Otherwise, it does not.

Comment: What I mean by that is that the method `applicationDidFinishLaunching` will be invoked before going to `connection:didReceiveResponse` and downloading the JSON feed. When in fact I need my JSON feed downloaded before `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is complete.

Comment: I would say that you need to revisit your design of your application then.  Without knowing what you are doing in applicationDidFinishLaunching, it is hard to suggest anything specific, but there's no reason why you couldn't trigger a change of your application after it has finished downloading the file.