# NSData / Retrieving content from a page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsurlconnection

I have a page that displays one string on a blank page. I need to retrieve that string. How would I do it if I wanted to do it both, synchronously and asynchronously? (I would appreciate if someone gave me the method names for both synch and asynch).

Thank you,

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491066/multithreading-and-json-nsurlconnection-on-the-iphone

Comment: @Bavarious this is completely different. I am asking a specific question here regarding a specific implementation. That question was a question about the general approach. I did not want to combine both together and make it confusing. Furthermore, separating the questions would make it easier for people who have the same problem and looking online for answers.

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:nsurlconnection], so you must already be looking in the right place. Are you having some specific problem with that class, or do you just want a general tutorial on downloading data from a server?

Comment: @Caleb I know how to download data from a server. I am downloading a page that contains nothing but a string. So after I get the "NSData", how would I extract the string into an NSString from it?

Comment: You can't have a string on a blank page. It won't be blank anymore.

Comment: @WTP X: blank page. Y: a string. Y on X = a string ON a blank page = a page with a string only.

Comment: @Nayefc If I write ink ON a blank page, the page is still blank?

Comment: @Nayefc, NSString has a method called `-initWithData:encoding:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference.  The methods you want are there.  Also, read the [URL Loading guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i), it has some code examples for both synchronous and asynchronous loading.

The body data of the repsonse will be the string you want.  You'll need to be a bit careful about which encoding was used by the web site.  If not specified in the response at all, it will be ISO-8859-1, otherwise it will probably be specified in the Content-Type header of the response.  You then need to convert the data to an NSString with initWithData:encoding:

NB if you are not on the main thread, you can use NSStering's [stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJHDDAJ).  You shouldn't use this on the main thread because it is a synchronous method.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyP. Yes I know that. I've been using NSURLConnection for a while. However, I've used it with JSON and RSS feeds only. I've been looking for a way to just get the page content. If I "get data" and the page only has a string (on a blank page), would NSData actually just be made of that string? If so, how can I extract that string into an NSString?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSString`'s [`stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL%3aencoding%3aerror%3a) method to get the HTML page synchronously and later parse it using [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Since `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` is a blocking call, you should put it in a method and invoke the method using [`performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground%3awithObject%3a). This will retrieve the HTML page in the background.

Once you have the string, create an instance of `NSXMLParser` and get the string. This one is asynchronous process.

Few examples on how to use `NSXMLParser` - [`Make NSXMLParser your friend`](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) and [`BNR - Parsing XML in Cocoa`](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48).